# In Spring security how to re-authenticate account after restart server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security in Spring Boot  to secure my web,but the Authentication stays after I restart server, so ,how to re-authenticate after I reboot my server?

more specific ,I login : http://localhost:8080/  success,now I restart my Spring boot project . Then I refresh that page but no authentication ,also , it's not redirect to login page .  I want to know the logic implementation in Spring Security ?

In my view ,when server restart ,all authentication and session should be clear ,But why and how  this happened?

I enable sessions :

```
 @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http//.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authentication")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/",true)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/login?expired")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry);
```

And define some beans :

```
@Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
```

I have used  user details :

```
    @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            //Mysql authentication
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```